# How to make maximum failed login attempt for user to 3 time only after that block it?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I work on web application `asp.net mvc core .net 5` i can't modify action login

to accept 3 login attempt failed only .

if he try with wrong password or wrong email account after that then block it .

I using user identity login

what I try

```
[HttpPost]
   public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginVM loginVM)
   {
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View(loginVM);

    var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(loginVM.EmailAddress);
    if(user != null)
    {
        var passwordCheck = await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, loginVM.Password);
        if (passwordCheck)
        {
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, loginVM.Password, false, false);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Movies");
            }
        }
        TempData["Error"] = "Wrong credentials. Please, try again!";
        return View(loginVM);
    }

    TempData["Error"] = "Wrong credentials. Please, try again!";
    return View(loginVM);
}
```

**updated post**
can you help me by solution general working as session without using identity membership so i can use it on another login or another logic

Comment: can you help me to block user failed login maximum 3 time for user based on session

Comment: i need solution used on general solution as identity or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are trying with Identity ,You Could try as below ：

```
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);
```

If you set lockoutOnFailure: true,when someone login with wrong password ,the number of  AccessFailedCount column would  add 1

And you could set the MaxFailedAccessAttempts as below in startup:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<AppUser>(options => 
                         { 
                           options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
                           options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 3;
                           options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

                         })
```

**Accroding to your Update:**

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Login(User user)
        {
            
            
            string failure;

            HttpContext.Request.Cookies.TryGetValue("LoginInfo", out failure);
            int fail = Convert.ToInt32(failure);

            if (fail > 3)
            {
                //You could add ModelState here and retrun current Page ,it dependens on how your frontend designed 
                return View("Failure");
            }

            // your login attempts here

            //var passwordCheck = await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(......);
            //............

            //If failed

            fail += 1;
           

            HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("LoginInfo", fail.ToString());           

            return View();
        }
```

Result:

[image]

Tried with a middleware；

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    string failure;
    int fail = 0;
    context.Request.Cookies.TryGetValue("LoginFailure", out failure);
    fail = Convert.ToInt32(failure);
    if (fail >= 3&& context.Request.Path.Value.Contains("Login"))
    {
        context.Response.Redirect("/Home/Wait");
    }
    await next.Invoke();

    if (context.Items.ContainsKey("Fail"))
    {
        fail += 1;
        context.Response.Cookies.Append("LoginFailure", fail.ToString());
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for reply but how to add it on login fully action after add you code

Comment: can you help me to add action with you modifications please

Comment: You could try with the codes in controller/MiddleWare/Filter,I'll show how it works in a middleware few minutes later